# Why does phantomJS 2.1.1 render this page as background color with no content, but foxshot 1.2.0 renders it correctly?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, headless

I like to keep track of Massachusetts lottery results (make sure the results are really random). I can bring up the page of results in any browser and copy-paste the lines of text, and run the text through a filter written in php or gawk to extract the numbers for each date. But I thought it would be nicer to automate the process using phantomJS to get the dates and numbers directly from the DOM.

I haven't been able to make this work because the elements containing the results do not appear to be in the DOM accessible through phantomJS. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong (I probably am) or if it's a problem with phantomJS (which I know is no longer maintained). But I also tried using the example of rendering a URL to a .png image directly from the **Page Loading** example in the [quickstart](https://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html), and the image came out as just background color with no text, so I'm thinking it's a problem with phantomJS. Or does that example need some extra code to wait for all the included scripts to complete?

Here is the example javascript with the URL in question and image filename hardwired:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.masslottery.com/tools/past-results/mega-millions?start_date=2021-09-03&end_date=2021-09-28', function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {
        page.render('example.png');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Running phantomjs on the above javascript produces this file named example.png as follows:
[image: example.png]

But running [foxshot](https://github.com/potch/foxshot) I see the following:

```
$ foxshot 'https://www.masslottery.com/tools/past-results/mega-millions?start_date=2021-09-03&end_date=2021-09-28'
no valid dimensions provided, defaulting to 1024x768
loading site...
1024x768
```

And it produces a file named screenshot_1024x768.png as follows:
[image: screenshot_1024x768.png]

Of course foxshot doesn't provide a way to access the DOM or otherwise access the text displayed in the image. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer? It is actively maintained and should be able to render pages to images/pdfs and evaluate javascript on-page. Also if you only need to scrap dates (without rendering images), you don't need a headless browser, you could download HTML with fetch or superagent and then parse it with regexp or https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: I tried wget and curl, and neither one of them get the content I'm looking for, Guess I'll try puppeteer. I did update the question to include one of the specific tests I tried to access the DOM with phantomJS. Hope puppeteer can do better. If so, and if you write this comment as an answer, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this with [puppeteer](http://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

```
//npm i puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

!(async () => {
  //open browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  //open browser page
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  //open url
  await page.goto('https://www.masslottery.com/tools/past-results/mega-millions?start_date=2021-09-03&end_date=2021-09-28')
  //wait for table to appear
  await page.waitForSelector('.multi-col-stacking-table')
  //iterate over table rows on page
  const data = await page.$$eval('.multi-col-stacking-table tbody tr', d =>
    d.map(d => ({
      //format date as YYYY-MM-DD
      date: new Date(d.querySelector('.past-results-row-draw-date').innerText).toJSON().slice(0, 10),
      //collect winning numbers
      winningNumber: Array.from(d.querySelectorAll('.winning-number-ball-circle, .winning-number-ball-circle-no-border')).map(d => +d.innerText),
      //get multiplier as number
      multiplier: +d.querySelector('.winning-number-ball-multiplier').innerText.slice(0, -1),
      //parse jackpot into number - remove all non-digits and multiply by 1M
      jackpot: +d.querySelector('.jackpot').innerText.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') * 1e6
    }))
  )
  console.log(data)
  //optional screenshot
  await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'})
  await browser.close()
})()

//output
/*
[
  {
    date: '2021-09-27',
    winningNumber: [ 18, 30, 43, 68, 69, 22 ],
    multiplier: 4,
    jackpot: 22000000
  },
  {
    date: '2021-09-23',
    winningNumber: [ 17, 21, 27, 43, 56, 15 ],
    multiplier: 3,
    jackpot: 20000000
  },
  ...
]
*/
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I did install nvm/npm/node and then puppeteer, and tried to get something like this to work.  But I was unable to get the textContent. I used " const td_elements = await page.$$('TABLE.multi-col-stacking-table')", then iterated over td_elements, with "td_elements[i].getProperty('textContent').then(success, failure)".  But it always called the failure callback with Protocol Error.

Comment: Also, the syntax of the 2nd arg to $$eval,  ' d =>
    d.map(d => {
      return {' totally mystifies me. So I just googled it and see that it's some fancy js shortcut for writing an anonymous function definition - as if javascript needed to be more terse :-)  So thanks again!! But the reason I couldn't get my approach to work eludes me.

Comment: Okay, so after finding out the name of the construct is "arrow functions", I had to google that and found out: "JavaScript arrow functions arrived with the release of ECMAScript 2015, also known as ES6." And what little I know about javascript came around 2013, before such a thing existed. Now I feel slightly less ignorant.

Comment: Glad to help :)